# Tagging user Autocomplete Pop-UP doesn't work on mobile website

Tags: feature-request, bug, mobile-web, comment-replies

Why doesn't tagging user work on Stackoverflow mobile site version ?

**Working desktop feature**

[image: working desktop feature]

---

**Non working mobile feature**

[image: non working mobile feature]

To avoid further arguments , please try the feature on your own phone , or propose a good reason of why it may not be wokring as expected.

Comment: When tagging isn't necessary, it doesn't work on the main site either (for example, I can't tag @P... well, it doesn't work here either because there is no ambiguity in who the message is going to).  See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/

Comment: @MichaelT my question is clear the feature is working on desktop version but not working on mobile , i uploaded new images to clarify the point.

Comment: It's not the _tagging_ that doesn't work, but the _auto-complete feature_ of usernames, looks like.

Comment: @Kendra no it was not working for long time even when i used original keyboard , i just thought to wait till they fix the issue , the autocomplete will not work unless you tap the word , a native feature doesnt relate to a web at all.

Comment: @ProllyGeek I don't mean your phone's auto-complete, I mean the site's auto-complete that pops up when you start typing in a username. Once again, _tagging_ works, but the username pop-up is what isn't working.

Comment: @Kendra are you saying that if i manually tag the user , he/she will get notified even if auto-complete doesnt work ?

Comment: I do. Try tagging me using your phone in your next comment. Just because the username doesn't pop up on mobile doesn't mean it won't work- It's probably a limitation that has to do with mobile, or a design choice to keep the screen from getting too cluttered when there are many usernames that could be selected.

Comment: @Kendra did this work ?

Comment: Yes it did. :) You're all good to go, friend.

Comment: @Kendra interesting , then it is only the pop-up that doesnt work , but from user experience prespective this is not good .

Answer (score 2):

As also stated in my answer to [my own question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392815/nickname-auto-completion-in-comments-doesnt-work-in-mobile-version-of-the-site?noredirect=1&lq=1) (marked as dupe of this one) it seems that the missing "Suggested people feature" on mobile version of the website is a known limitation that is not going to be supported.

According to this Meta SE answer, in fact

```
The [missing auto-completion feature] is by design -- the mobile site has limited functionality and name autocomplete is not supported on it.
```

It is actually an old answer (2014), and actually something changed since then: the mobile the version of the site specifically designed for mobile is obsolete and no longer being actively maintained.

Any user should instead use the responsive view of the site, even from mobile phone because it is better in every way. If you are using the old mobile version you can switch to responsive view by clicking on "full site" link in the footer. Responsiveness can also be enabled/disabled there, too, but you don't want to disable it on mobile for obvious reasons.

With the responsive view version of the site nickname suggestion in comments works also from mobile phones.