# Nickname auto-completion in comments doesn't work in mobile version of the site

Tags: feature-request, bug, comments

Since I often browse SO questions from my phone, some times I need to comment in order to ask clarification or to provide some help.

But the nickname auto-completion of the user, that for the desktop version of the site work fine

[image]

in the mobile version of the site doesn't work/is not implemented. This is a problem because *pinging* another user is sometimes required.

It would be great having this useful feature in all the versions of the site, mainly because I'm not completely sure about the way the ping can be written manually (nicknames with spaces and more special characters).

Comment: Doesn't address the bug but, you only need to type the first 3 characters of a users name to ping them (assuming the first 3 characters are uniquely identifying for the post), so in your example you could ping with just `@P__`, and you could be pinged on this post (if you weren't OP) using `@Cub`. Additionally special characters are replaced with normal ones, Jóhn can be pinged with `@John` and spaces are ignored, J Smith would be `@JSmith` or `@JSm`

Comment: @NickA Really? And what about capital/lower characters? I think it would be easier to understand if a nick was correctly pinged if it was in some way hilighted in the output comment.

Comment: IIRC it's case insensitive, you can definitely use all lowercase

Comment: As a more senior user of this site, I still have trouble being confident in whether or not I have pinged someone properly on mobile; I actually hesitate to ping people until I can get back to my PC. I think that this would make for a good feature request. Even on desktop it isn't obvious that special chars are replaced with normal ones because as soon as you type a normal char in place of a special one then it stops suggesting that user. Even on https://stackoverflow.com/users I cannot find `wiktor stribizew` without using the special char.

Comment: This isn't a bug.  It is a feature that doesn't exist in the mobile site.  And it's been a long standing issue

Comment: @psubsee2003 It actually does. I don't know why I didnt' find it (I searched for duplicates before asking). Or, lets say... it would answer my question if it had an answer. For me it is ok to close my question... but I would like to have an feedback from a site developer, indeed.

Comment: @Cubo78 answer from a Dev over on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177621/using-so-on-a-mobile-device/231607#231607

Comment: @psubsee2003 Ok, this one definitely answers my question, though it is not the answer I would have preferred.

Comment: It works perfectly for me on mobile; I use it regularly. Make sure that you're using the *responsive view* of the site, not the version specifically designed for mobile. The latter is obsolete and no longer being actively maintained. The responsive version is better in every way anyway. Use a link in the footer to switch back and forth. (Responsiveness can also be enabled/disabled there, too, but you don't want to disable it on mobile for obvious reasons.)

Comment: See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) in order to gain confidence that you are using these correctly and that the intended target will be notified. I rarely type out the whole username; it takes up too much space in the comment box and adds too much noise. I can type 3 characters an order of magnitude faster than I can select something with my mouse, or even wait out the lag period for a tooltip to appear. @mon

Comment: @CodyGray The mistery thickens... I'm still not able to see any responsive link. Ps: I don't think that closing a question because it is a duplicate of a question that has no answer is a good idea.

Comment: Oh! I found it! I had to select full site! That's THE answer!

Comment: @Cubo78 you should edit your answer with the info you learned from Cody Gray.  old Mobileview -> autocomplete does not work.  new responsive design for the full site works on mobile and supports autocomplete

Comment: @psubsee2003 Done! Now we have a duplicate question with a complete answer! :)

Comment: @CodyGray I've read that wiki several times and understand it. It still doesn't help from a UX and discoverability standpoint for anyone not aware of that post. No suggestions is heavily connotative with failing to use the feature. This is doubly true for trying to ping a post editor who has not commented.

Comment: @CodyGray This post is still marked as a duplicate of a question without answers. Should I copy the answer below answering the "original post"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the missing *"Suggested people feature"* on mobile version of the website is a known limitation that is not going to be supported.

According to this [Meta SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177621/using-so-on-a-mobile-device/231607#231607), in fact

> The [missing auto-completion feature] is by design -- the mobile site
>   has limited functionality and name autocomplete is not supported on
>   it.

It is actually an old answer (2014), and actually something changed since then: the mobile the version of the site specifically designed for mobile is obsolete and no longer being actively maintained.

Any user should instead use **the responsive view of the site**, even from mobile phone because it is better in every way. If you are using the old mobile version you can switch to responsive view by clicking on ***"full site"*** link in the footer. Responsiveness can also be enabled/disabled there, too, but you don't want to disable it on mobile for obvious reasons.

**With the responsive view version of the site nickname suggestion in comments works also from mobile phones.**